# Error: Call to a member function newEntity() on boolean

Tags: cakephp

I am new on cakephp. I have done all the required steps but still having trouble in saving data in database with cakephp

code of adduser function from Articlecontroller.php:

```
public function adduser()
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());

        // Hardcoding the user_id is temporary, and will be removed later
        // when we build authentication out.
        $user->user_id = 1;

        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
    }
    $this->set('article', $user);
}
```

code of UserTable model:

```
<?php
// src/Model/Table/ArticlesTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }
}
```

Data Base Table onto my locahost:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you forgot to load User model in controller. It should be fixed adding this line in function adduser() before first line. It should look like this.

```
public function adduser()
{
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
...
```

Cakephp documentation.
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to have a CakePHP application that is using the plugin. You need to add $this->loadComponent('Auth'); to your AppControllers initialize() method and configure it properly.

I highly recommend you to do the complete blog tutorial of the official CakePHP documentation or you won't have much fun with any plugin or anything else in the framework. It covers setting up Auth as well.

Answer (score 0):

As other have started, when not in the controller related to the table you're accessing, you need to load the model and its related entities.

The current way of retrieving a table is through the table registry, as shown below:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

// Now $articles is an instance of our ArticlesTable class. This is how CakePHP 4 prefers it.
$articles = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Articles');

// Prior to 3.6.0
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
```

So for your public method, it should look like this:

```
public function adduser()
{
    $usersTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');
    $user = $usersTable->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      ...code for handling post...
    }
 }
```

[The CakePHP 3.x (and beyond) documentation regarding ORM outlines this well](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html#quick-example). While `$this->loadModel('Articles')` work, a quick search through the docs shows it is not frequently referred to neither in ORM section nor in examples.